# How to autoplay HTML5 mp4 video on Android?

Tags: android, html, html5-video

I had developed a mobile page by asp.net to play mp4 video.

I know iOS had disabled the autoplay function to minimize user bandwidth, so how can i 
autoplay HTML5 mp4 video on Android ?

I had already put autoplay in HTML5 code, but it doesn't work.

The following is my code:

```
<video autoplay controls id='video1' width='100%' poster='images/top_icon.png' webkitEnterFullscreen poster preload='true'>
<source src='http://192.xxx.xxx.xx/XXXXVM01.mp4' type='video/mp4; codecs='avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2' >
</video>
```

Moreover, I had fixed the problem that user click on the image overlay can play the video.
Thanks Karthi

here are the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#video1").bind("click", function() {
    var vid = $(this).get(0);
    if (vid.paused) { vid.play(); }
    else { vid.pause(); }
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Thanks

Joe

Comment: If you want to play the video while clicking poster, then create an image overlay , while onclick on that image overlay play the video

Comment: Thanks Karthi, i had created an image overlay. it works.

Comment: Since Android 4.2+ the **autoplay** html5 attribute for video is not supported. The video will only start to play after user clicks on it. In order to handle this you can use Modernizr "videoautoplay" feature (https://modernizr.com/download?videoautoplay-setclasses) that adds the class "videoautoplay" or "no-videoautoplay" on html tag.

Comment: Care to accept [AngryFridges' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075520/how-to-autoplay-html5-mp4-video-on-android/40718904#40718904)? That's at least a partial solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think autoplay works on Android, but getting a video to play can be annoyingly tricky. I suggest giving this article a read: [Making HTML5 Video work on Android phones](http://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/08/making-html5-video-work-on-android-phones/).

Comment: Nowadays adding `muted` for silent video, as described in [AngryFridges' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075520/how-to-autoplay-html5-mp4-video-on-android/40718904#40718904) provides at least a partial solution.

Answer (score 32):

You can add the 'muted' and 'autoplay' attributes together to enable autoplay for android devices.

e.g.

```html
<video id="video" class="video" autoplay muted >
```

Comment: Thanks. ! This is correct answer as of now. adding "muted" works like charm. no other options are available right now as browser requires user gesture to play video otherwise cannot.

Comment: For a video without sound this is the perfect solution, thank you!

Comment: Check https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/autoplay, seems to stop working

Answer (score 22):

I used the following code:

```
// get the video
var video = document.querySelector('video');
// use the whole window and a *named function*
window.addEventListener('touchstart', function videoStart() {
  video.play();
  console.log('first touch');
  // remove from the window and call the function we are removing
  this.removeEventListener('touchstart', videoStart);
});
```

There doesn't seem to be a way to auto-start anymore.

This makes it so that the first time they touch the screen the video will play. It will also remove itself on first run so that you can avoid multiple listeners adding up.

Comment: Wow, your answer is really interesting. Worked well here. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for a very clever and minimal solution.

Comment: On chrome on android, this also appears to have now been blocked, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6):

Android actually has an API for this!  The method is [setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(boolean)).  I found it after a lot of digging into video autoplay and a lot of attempted hacks from SO.  Here's an example from [blair vanderhoof](https://gist.github.com/blairvanderhoof/9380545):

```
package com.example.myProject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;

public class myProject extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

        WebSettings ws = super.appView.getSettings();
        ws.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Android 4.4 and above you can remove the need for a user gesture so long as the HTML5 Video component lives in your own WebView

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webview.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

To get the video to autoplay, you'd still need to add autoplay to the video element:

```
<video id='video' controls autoplay>
  <source src='http://192.xxx.xxx.xx/XXXXVM01.mp4' type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' >
</video>
```

Comment: From where does the webview come in this case? Meaning, if this is not JS, then please state that.

Answer (score 4):

Important Note: Be aware that if Google Chrome Data Saver is enabled in Chrome's settings, then Autoplay will be disabled.

Answer (score 3):

Autoplay only works the second time through. 
on android 4.1+ you have to have some kind of user event to get the first play() to work. Once that has happened then autostart works.

This is so that the user is acknowledging that they are using bandwidth.

There is another question that answers this .
[Autostart html5 video using android 4 browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758651/autostart-html5-video-using-android-4-browser)

Comment: this is such bullshit, but thanks for confirming this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

similar to KNaito's answer, the following does the trick for me

```
function simulateClick() {
  var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true
  });
  var cb = document.getElementById('player'); 
  var canceled = !cb.dispatchEvent(event);
  if (canceled) {
    // A handler called preventDefault.
    alert("canceled");
  } else {
    // None of the handlers called preventDefault.
    alert("not canceled");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android 4.1 and 4.2, I use the following code.

```
    evt.initMouseEvent( "click", true,true,window,0,0,0,0,0,false,false,false,false,0, true );
    var v = document.getElementById("video");
    v.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

where html is

```
    <video id="video" src="sample.mp4" poster="image.jpg" controls></video>
```

This works well. But In Android 4.4, it does not work.

Comment: In 4.4 you can use:  `webview.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);` in native code.

Comment: what is "evt"? is this one of the couple answers targetting PhoneGap and friends without acknowledging it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plugin for PhoneGap which solved the problem for me:
https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1031

I simply included it in my config.xml

Answer (score 0):

```
<video autoplay controls id='video1' width='100%' poster='images/top_icon.png' webkitEnterFullscreen poster preload='true'>
<source src='http://192.xxx.xxx.xx/XXXXVM01.mp4' type='video/mp4; codecs='avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2' >
</video>
```

Comment: I've tried the several attributes you added above, but none make the video autoplay on my Samsung Android phone or tablet. (`muted` does the trick for me, as described in another answer.)

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the Javascript to trigger the video to start.

```js
 var bg = document.getElementById ("bg"); 
 function playbg() {
   bg.play(); 
 }
```

```html
<video id="bg" style="min-width:100%; min-height:100%;"  playsinline autoplay loop muted onload="playbg(); "><source src="Files/snow.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

*"Files/snow.mp4" is just sample url

Answer (score 0):

Can add `muted` tag.

```
<video autoplay muted>
  <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm" />
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

reference https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/autoplay

Answer (score 0):

don't use "mute" alone, use [muted]="true" for example following code:

```
<video id="videoPlayer" [muted]="true" autoplay playsinline loop style="width:100%; height: 100%;">
<source type="video/mp4" src="assets/Video/Home.mp4">
<source type="video/webm" src="assets/Video/Home.webm">
</video>
```

I test in more Android and ios

Answer (score -1):

Chrome has disabled it. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=159336
Even the jQuery play() is blocked. They want user to initiate it so bandwidth can be saved.

Comment: jQuery have never had a `play` method. Any `play` method you call is not provided by jQuery.