# html5 video autoplay not working in android 4.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm stuck in a project where I want to auto play video using [html5 video](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp).  It works fine on desktop browser, but on Android 4.1 default browser it requires me to "touch" (or click) video element (or play button)to play video.

I have tried number of ways:

- use [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)
- manually calling play function on page load
- using autoplay attribute

but none of above works in Android browser.

One solution which I think is to simulate click event on page load but is it programmatically possible to simulate click function?

Comment: You cannot force mobile users to autoplay video. It's a feature of the OS. It's to do with the cost of mobile bandwidth and the OS creators doing what's the in the best interests of the user.

Comment: @ahren i know its os feature but its for my client project so i am doing it for wat it is he ask for... secondly i found that if i could simulate click on element it can appear as autoplay

Comment: You can't do it. Simulated clicks don't count on the video element in most mobile OS's...

Comment: @ahren anyother way to perform autoplay for video

Answer (score 0):

Referring [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27952393/3518991).

For Android < 4.2.2 it seems that the last DOM event you get is `loadeddata`. You likely won't get `canplaythrough`. To autoplay, you then use javascript

```
var myvideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0]; 
myvideo.play();
```

For Android 4.2.2+ all you need in your native code is

```
WebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```