# How to "autoplay" HTML5 video on Android tablet

Tags: android, html5-video, autoplay

I have built a simple application for my Samsung tablet with some HTML5 video set to be played automatically. But auto play not working in my tablet and also i cannot find any working solution how to enable auto play. please help me

Comment: Mobile devices limit the use of autoplay due to bandwidth issues. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758651/autostart-html5-video-using-android-4-browser

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me. I am doing it in js.

```
 setTimeout(function () {  
     $("#myvideotag").get[0].play();  
 }, 100);
```

Hope it will help. Let me know if you have some concerns regarding this.