# html5 video autoplay on android chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, mobile, html5-video

Simple question: 
is there a way to get video autoplay working on android chrome?
To get working I mean also if there's a workaround.

I looked around and seems I can't. Is it right?

Thank you

Comment: Play on first user interaction: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11825976/1293492

Comment: Use a .gif animation.

Answer (score 0):

Add att `muted`

```
<video autoplay muted>
  <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm" />
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```