# Autoplay attribute for HTML 5 in android devieces

Tags: android, html5-video

I am trying to integrate an HTML 5 video player with It's auto-play attribute on my site. It is working fine on Web and other devices but it is not working with any android device which has 4.0 and above OS. I have seen this [Link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=159336).But I am looking if there is any workaround for this issue.

**Note**:I have also tried implementing jwplayer but later on I found that it doesn't support the autoplay for android and ios devices.

PS : I have tried to put an image on top of video and clicking on that should trigger an autoplay but still no success.

Answer (score 0):

The only approach I know of is to provide a user interaction before the video begins to play like a 'touch to enter site' button, then on that event play the video. Playing video or audio in HTML5 requires user interaction on Android and iOS. It is by design - no workaround as of today is available. You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075520/how-to-autoplay-html5-mp4-video-on-android) for confirmation.

You can read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/audiovideo/conceptual/using_html5_audio_video/device-specificconsiderations/device-specificconsiderations.html) for the whys and hows on iOS (which is the same info as on your Google link).