# Jplayer does not start playing automatically on mobile device

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, jplayer

JPlayer does not start playing automatically after setMedia() followed by play() on mobile device (Android), but works fine on chrome for PC and even internet explorer, what should i do to get it playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behaviour. On mobile devices playback must be initiated by user interaction. Take a look here for more details -> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075520/how-to-autoplay-html5-mp4-video-on-android)

Comment: So what do i have to do?

Comment: I do not think that there will be one "hack" to rule all Android versions. I guess the best way will be to encourage user to start playing video by touching play button.