# Make .webm auto-play on Android?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a site which starts with a .webm playing in a HTML5-video box. It does work fine on my computer using Chrome or Firefox, however on my mobile phone (Android) it does not auto play. The `src` of the video is appended via AJAX, so as soon as it's been added to the html5 video, so I've tried to make this call right after:

```
var videoLOL = document.getElementById('video');
videoLOL.play();
```

..but it's not working (never mind the variable name). Ideas?

EDIT: Some code

```
<video autoplay="" style="max-width:720px;max-height:406px;width:100%;height:100%;" id="video" src="" loop="">
</video>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to autoplay HTML5 mp4 video on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075520/how-to-autoplay-html5-mp4-video-on-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mobile browsers are not supporting autoplay. iOS and Android dosen't support it, because the user high speed volume should not be wasted anymore. Get sure, that you get an `poster="example.jpg"` on your video.

Comment: A poster will do fine. Thanks.