# HTML5 Video autoplay in Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, video.js

I am developing an html5 player supports ads with `video-js`

Since i know it doesn't work in iOS, is it the same on Android?

So far i've tried these with no luck on autoplay in Android

**HTML**

```
  <video id="inReadPlayer" autoplay loop="loop" 
    controls preload="auto" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="640"
height="360" > <source src="'+videoSource+'" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

**JS**

```
 var player = videojs('inReadPlayer', { /* Options */ }, function() {
            this.play();
            this.on('ended', function() {

            });
 });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: it's like in iOS, so it won't work
look also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075520/how-to-autoplay-html5-mp4-video-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var videoplayer = document.getElementById('inReadPlayer')
videoplayer.addEventListener("load", function() {
videoplayer.play();
});
videoplayer.onended = function() {
source.setAttribute('src', 'MAINVIDEO.mp4');

};
```

```html
  <video id="inReadPlayer" autoplay loop="loop" 
    controls preload="auto" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="640"
height="360" > <source src="'+videoSource+'" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

> Note that this snippet won't work because there is no video source