# Mute and autoplay video on mobile devices using angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, angular, html5-video

I am using html5 video tag in angular 4 app to autoplay video in background. I am unable to auto mute the video and because of that video is not autoplaying on mobile devices. Code I am using is:

```
<video playsinline autoplay loop controls = "controls" muted = "muted">
   <source src="banner-video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   <source src="banner-video.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>
```

PS: Video is autoplaying on laptop but is not getting auto muted.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Mute it by clicking some button?

Comment: @LeoOdishvili No, not by click, I want auto mute to work. Its not working

Comment: Then, I think the problem is that you are using XHTML syntax? Try to write <video playsinline autoplay loop controls = "controls" muted>

Answer (score 0):

Its like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075520/how-to-autoplay-html5-mp4-video-on-android), you can read: [Making HTML5 Video work on Android phones](https://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/08/making-html5-video-work-on-android-phones/) for tricky autoplay video.

But as described [AngryFridges's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075520/how-to-autoplay-html5-mp4-video-on-android/40718904#40718904) nowadays muted and autoplay for silent video, you can add the 'muted' and 'autoplay' attributes together to enable autoplay for android devices.

e.g.

```html
<video id="video" class="video" autoplay muted >
```